# The middle A of quadraginta

Tags: language-evolution, morphology, numbers, numerals

Consider these Latin cardinal numbers:
*quadrAginta*,
*quinquAginta*,
*sexAginta*,
*nonAginta*.
The *-ginta* seems to stand for tens (cf. *triginta, octoginta*) and the initial parts *quadr-*, *quinqu-*, *sex-*, and *non-* are easy to connect with 4, 5, 6, and 9, respectively.
The thing that puzzles me is the A in between (capitalized in the examples).
What is the origin of this A?
Do we know if it has a role or meaning?
Is it related to the other long A at the end?
I don't recall seeing a similar A binding two words together in a similar fashion in any other context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a messy point in Indo-European studies. Most of the many who have written on it think that the internal long ā originated in quadrāgintā and then spread by analogy to sexāgintā etc. The -rā- in quadrāgintā is then explained as the reflex of long syllabic /ṝ/, or as /r/ plus a laryngeal, or something like that. It is discussed in Sihler and de Vaan, in both cases somewhat differently, but along these general lines.

Comment: According to Weiss, the laryngeal was specifically the *h2 of the neuter plural ending.

Comment: Does r + h2 = rā? de Vaan says that “the long ā in quadrāginta (sic) must be phonetic”, which seems to be a way of saying that he has no explanation for it. @TKR

Comment: PIE *rH (when r is syllabic) gives Lat. rā for all laryngeals. "Must be phonetic" seems completely meaningless, I agree.